# C++ exposed property names don't match the names given in the IDL

Tags: c++, com, midl

In the IDL file for a C++ component I have something like the following, allowing the property to be COM visisble:

```
interface IInterface
{
    [propget, id(1), helpstring("the ID")]
         HRESULT ID([out, retval] long *pVal);
}
```

When I build the dll and open in OLEView I see something like this!?

```
interface IInterface
{
    [propget, id(0x00000001), helpstring("the ID")]
         HRESULT id([out, retval] long *pVal);
}
```

Notice that **ID** is showing as **id**.  However, if I modify this code, to say "ID2" then the **ID2** is shown as expected.  I then change back to "ID" and again **id** is shown.  This is pretty baffling to me.  There must be something on the machine which means the DLLs exposed name for this property is in lower case, but I can't find anything in the registry for this.

Any ideas? Very confused...

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this relates to the fact that [id has special meaning in IDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367040%28VS.85%29.aspx) (as your own example shows) - if it's not essential for you to name your property using an IDL keyword, I would just use a different name.

If you **must** use this name for the property for some reason, you may be able to use it in the uppercase form using the [rename attribute at import time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6zk74w.aspx).